# Добавить файл в ресурсы, а затем извлечь его

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resources

Хочу сделать, чтобы пользователь мог добавить файл в ресурсы программы, а затем была возможность извлечь его. С обеими задачи по отдельности я вроде как справилась, извлечь ресурс можно с помощью кода:

```cs
File.WriteAllBytes("test.sql", <Название проекта>.Properties.Resources.test);
```

Где `Resources.test` - нужный ресурс, а `"test.sql"` файл на диске.
Для добавления я взяла пример кода  с [документации Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcewriter.addresource?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#overloads):

```cs
// Get the image as an array of bytes.
FileStream byteStream = new FileStream("AppIcon.jpg", FileMode.Open);
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[(int) byteStream.Length];
byteStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int) byteStream.Length);
          
// Create the resource file.
using (ResourceWriter rw = new ResourceWriter(@".\UIImages.resources"))
{
    rw.AddResource("AppIcon", byteStream);
    // Add any other resources.
}
```

Так как в примере работа с байтами, то можно вместо `.jpg` использовать другой формат, например `.sql` или `.exe`.

Так вот у меня два вопроса: **подойдёт ли этот метод с документации Microsoft для добавления любого формата файла?** И основной вопрос, который я не смогла решить - **как можно извлечь записанный ресурс?** Ведь используя метод, который я приводила в пример выше:

```cs
File.WriteAllBytes("test.sql", <Название проекта>.Properties.Resources.test);
```

нужно указывать путь к ресурсу `Properties.Resources.<ресурс>`, но так как ресурса в программе ещё нет, то я не знаю, как правильно это сделать. Возможно есть другие методы добавления / извлечения ресурсов, которые позволяют это сделать. И возможно ли это сделать на С#? Первый пример, который приходит в голову, доказывающий, что это в принципе возможно, -  обфускаторы кода, ведь в них ты указываешь файл, затем происходит его обфускация и на выходе мы получаем новый файл. Возможно я что-то не так понимаю и в них используется другая логика, углублённо в этой теме я не разбираюсь. Также я нашла код изменения уже добавленного файла ресурсов:

```cs
string ResxFile = File.ReadAllText("Properties/Resources.resx");
string wordResxName = resxname;
string word = resxvalue;
string ResxAddStrings = "  <data name=\"" + wordResxName + "\" xml:space=\"preserve\">\r\n    <value>" + word + "</value>\r\n  </data>\r\n";
ResxAddStrings += "</root>";
File.WriteAllText("Properties/Resources.resx", ResxFile);
```

Со статьями [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcewriter.addresource?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#overloads), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps), и [3](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/aa992030(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) я уже ознакомилась. Также долгое время искала ответ на свой вопрос в сети, но ответа на него не нашла. Возможно вы знаете что-то по этой теме и подскажете мне?

Comment: [Оно?](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/resources/working-with-resx-files-programmatically)

Comment: @aepot, да, спасибо большое!

Comment: А что значит «извлечь»? Скопировать в файл на диске?

Comment: @VladD да, извлечь на диск, ну или скопировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно извлечь конкретный ресурс по имени, используя класс System.Resources.ResXResourceSet . Метод ResourceSet.GetString(String) извлекает значение именованного строкового ресурса. Метод ResourceSet.GetObject(String) извлекает значение именованного объекта или двоичные данные. Этот метод возвращает объект, который затем должен быть приведен (в C#) или преобразован (в Visual Basic) в объект нужного типа.